# Airflow command not found for all commands

Tags: airflow

I am getting an error when attempting to create a user. I have Airflow running on Unbunto Virtualbox and I am SSH from Visual Studio Code. As a sanity test, I ran airflow scheduler and got a "command not found" again. Attempted to run the command with sudo as well.

[image: error screen shot]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if you are working in the sandbox and close out virtual studio code you need to get back in the sandbox and then run the commands.

```
>source sandbox/bin/activate
>airflow db init
>airflowebserver
```